# Invalid Column Name | C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection

I am trying to figure out how to collect data from a database with c#.
I am stuck on a SQL command, and I can't really figure out how to fix it.
My error is: Invalid Column Name

This is my database:
[MyDatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTzVU.png)

And this is my connection class:

```
namespace CarDAL
{
    public class ConnectionClass
    {
        private string Connectionstring =
            "MYCONNECTIONSTRING";


        public List<string> SoortSelectList(string KarakterSoort)
        {
            KarakterSoort = "Defensive";
            List<string> soortList = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Karakter WHERE KarakterSoort = Defensive", connection))
                {
                    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            soortList.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                            soortList.Add(dr.GetValue(1).ToString());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return soortList;
        }
```

I think after WHERE that the problem is, but I don't know (and can't find) the right solution for my problem.

Comment: In addition to @marc_s answer....your passing in a string "KarakterSoort" and then you setting the string to "Defensive"....then (I think) your trying to use that string in SELECT string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause here:

```
WHERE KarakterSoort = Defensive
```

compares the value in the `KarakterSoort` column to the value in the `Defensive` column.

Is that really what you want???

Quite possibly, you want to compare to a string literal - then you need to put this into **single quotes** like this:

```
WHERE KarakterSoort = 'Defensive'
```

Now you're selecting all rows where the `KarakterSoort` column contains the **value** `Defensive`

Or if you might want compare to some other value in the future - use a **parameter** in your query string:

```
WHERE KarakterSoort = @DesiredValue
```

and declare it

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DesiredValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
```

and set its value before your run the command:

```
cmd.Parameters["@DesiredValue"].Value = "Defensive";
```

Comment: If it answered the question, @JosseLardinois, you should mark the answer as the solution.